# Simulate an asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, promise

Hi I'm trying to understand how Promises works and how to simulate an asynchronous call to be used as a test on a React component.

I wrote this code but the final effect is that the data are loaded immediately instead of waiting for the delay time.

Where am I doing wrong? 

thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export default class Test extends Component 
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        sleep(3000).then(
            this.setState({
                data: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
            })
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.data.map(function(value, index){
                    return <li key={index}>{value}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `.then` expects a function as it's (one or two) arguments - not a piece of code - so `sleep(3000).then(() =>` ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are *calling* the function `setState` immediately instead of passing a function reference to `then`.

You can get a function reference in several ways: one is by using `bind`. Change this:

```
    sleep(3000).then(
        this.setState({
            data: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
        })
    );
```

to:

```
    sleep(3000).then(
        this.setState.bind(this, {
            data: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
        })
    );
```

Alternatively, you can create a function more explicitly:

```
    sleep(3000).then(
        _ => this.setState({
            data: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const getData = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const data = [
      {
        value: 10000000
      },
      {
        value: 20000000
      }
    ];
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data);
    }, 10);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can use the following to simulate asynchronous call:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export default class Test extends Component 
{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          data: []
      };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
    this.myFunc(data)
  }

  myFunc = async (data) => {        
    await sleep(3000)  
    this.setState({ data })
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(function(value, index){
            return <li key={index}>{value}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
        )
    }
}
```